# VBA Copy data from one sheet to another, if cell is empty, go onto next cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to write a code where if given a set of data on Sheet1:

For example:

```
     C
30   1234
31   0
32   0
33   56
34   789
```

(All these numbers range from 1-7 digits.)

I want to copy over the data onto Sheet2 like:

```
     X     Y     Z     Z     AA     AB     AC     AD
57                            1     2      3      4
58                                         5      6
59                                  7      8      9
```

And this is just a simple example, I have a long list of data that sometimes contains the number 0, but I only want numbers greater than zero copied onto Sheet2.

So far, this is the code I've written so far:

```
Sub IfBlankNext()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 99
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1).Value <> 0 Then
       {code code code}
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

For some reason, this code only returns the very last cell -- in this case, the cell data from Sheet1 Cell(99,3)

Comment: Your issue is probably in the `{code code code}` part... your loop appears to be set up to correctly go through rows `1 to 99` of column A.  If you only want cells greater than 0, you should probably use `>0` as the condition.  Can you add the additional code to your question?

Comment: @Byron The code I have in the IF statement is basically Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("X57").Formula = "_a formula such as MID() that can pull out one digit from each number depending on how long the number is and which cell the digit should go in_". This can come out pretty complicated and tedious looking, considering it's a lot of IF the number is 7 digits or 6 digits or... etc and MID() formulas within them, so is there an easier way to write that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before my code runs:

[image: Start]

```
Sub IfBlankNext()
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long, HoldVal As String
    'Define your last row of data by going to end and moving up:
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value > 0 Then
            'Define the LastCol on your destination sheet using similar method as row:
            DestLast = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If DestLast < 58 Then DestLast = 58
            HoldVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
            For x = 1 To Len(HoldVal)
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestLast, x + 23).Value = Mid(HoldVal, x, 1)
            Next x
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

After my code:

[image: End]

Code for changing cell alignment:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Name of Range").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft OR xlRight
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I should've been more specific with what I wanted the code to do in the end, but I edited my question. Thank you so much for coming up with a solution for my question before the revision though!

Comment: For some reason, I keep getting Error 424: Object required, and it refers to the DestLast = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1.

Comment: @Cindy it has to be "A" and DestLast refers to destination sheet which is "Sheet2" in my example. Check your Sheet names.

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually had the right sheet in my code, I just typed it out wrong in the comment. Also, for my data, in actuality, I want it to transfer over from the C column in Sheet1 to Column X in Sheet 2, so I rewrote my question again to be more specific!

Comment: This works for me.  Not sure about the downvote.  I had to `Dim x as Integer` as well but that's just only if `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @Chrismas007 This is great! Is there any way that the data could show up on Sheet2 starting on X58 as opposed to X2? And can it be right justified?

Comment: @Cindy Added code to start at `X58`.  Also, added the syntax for changing cell alignment.